# Problems with cross correlation in low-frequency data when computing phase lag of sin wave

Tags: matlab, statistics, cross-correlation

I am trying to compute the phase lag of a simple sin wave using a cross correlation in matlab.  Here is some code that demonstrates the problem I see.  (if you do not have the parallel computing toolbox you can adjust k and n accordingly and change the "parfor" to a "for").

```
clear all;
close all;

%%
knownLag = 1;

k  = 100000;
n = k/1000;


lag = zeros(1, n);
percentError = zeros(1, n);
m = zeros(1, n);

parfor i = 1:n;
    m(i) = i*2;
    x  = linspace(0, m(i)*pi, k);

    y1 = sin(x);
    y2 = sin(x+knownLag);

    %%
    [cc2, lags] = xcorr(y1, y2, 'coeff');
    [mx, I] = max(cc2);

    dx  = (m(i)*pi)/(k-1);
    lag(i) = (abs(k-I)*dx);

    percentError(i) = (abs(lag(i)-knownLag)/knownLag)*100;

end

figure(1);
plot(m, percentError)
ylabel('Percent Error');
xlabel('m * pi');

%%
n    = 1;
x1   = linspace(0, m(n)*pi, k);
y11  = sin(x1);
y21  = sin(x1+knownLag);

figure(2);
hold on;
plot(x1, y11);
plot(x1+lag(n), y21);
plot(x1, y21);
legend('Sin wave w/o phase shift', '"Corrected" Sin wave', '"Uncorrected" Sin wave');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('Plot of "Corrected" Sin wave with period = 2*pi');

n    = 5;
x1   = linspace(0, m(n)*pi, k);
y11  = sin(x1);
y21  = sin(x1+knownLag);

figure(3);
hold on;
plot(x1, y11);
plot(x1+lag(n), y21);
plot(x1, y21);
legend('Sin wave w/o phase shift', '"Corrected" Sin wave', '"Uncorrected" Sin wave');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('Plot of "Corrected" Sin wave with period = 10*pi');
```

Here are the plots of the output:
[image: Plot of error in predicted phase lag vs number of periods]
[image: Single period correction]
[image: Five period correction]

As you can see as the number of periods increase the error in predicted phase lag decreases.  Eventually numerics takes over and the error oscillates around a very low value.  I am really only interested in why there is such a strong decrease in error from 2-60 pi.  Is this an aliasing issue?  I don't understand where this comes from in the cross-correlation computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an aliasing issue. xcorr is an estimate of correlation between two signals. As you observe more of the signal your estimate will be better. For low values of `m*pi` the number of periods is low and your observation of signal is very limited. For higher values of `m*pi` you are getting better view of the signal's pattern with more periods which gives better estimate.

It is easy to understand when you think of one period of sine wave. When you align this period exactly on top of another you will get the maximum correlation. But this kind of alignment with a complete period does not happen when there is only one period of the signal with a lag since the edges are always padded with 0.

Comment: Could you explain more about the padding with zeros?

Comment: When xcorr slides one signal over the other the values in the non-overlapping region are assumed to be zeros. This is what I mean by padding.